# Sound on mouse hover, how?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please check out http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2004/10/24/application-xhtml+xml/

Every single link on the right hand column makes a small audible "bump" noise whenever the mouse pointer is hovering over it.

I inspected the CSS for the links but saw nothing relevant.

How is this done?

Comment: Good thing it doesn't work for me -- I get an error, both in Safari and Chrome: "Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. ping"... I'd hate to have a site that makes noise every time I move my mouse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Google Chrome, I right-clicked one of the `<li>`'s that "bumps" and chose *Inspect Element*.

From there, I chose *Event Listeners* > `mouseover` > `div#right`.

The `listenerBody` shows as:

```
$('right').onmouseover = function(e) {
      // so dirty.
      var o = (e.target?e.target:e.srcElement);
      if (o.tagName && o.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a' || (o.parentNode && o.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') || (o.className && Y.D.hasClass(o,'noisy'))) {
          soundManager.play('beep');    
}
```

It's on line 5,602 of http://www.schillmania.com/2009/2009.js

Comment: How do you get to "Event Listeners"?

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith I guess you have *Styles* expanded. Either collapse it, or scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Holy cow! Apparently in *this* case it's hybridized Flash-called-via-JavaScript. See http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2010/how-soundmanager2-works/ and http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ for the library.